# GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod

Tags: display, external-monitor, display-manager

I am getting the following error

> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such
>   interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2' on object at path
>   /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/XRANDR

whenever I try to apply any changes to the Display setting in the Ubutnu 12.04. I have a external monitor Dell S2240L connected to the laptop, both the display are working and mouse and windows can be moved between both the display without any problem.

I tried the answers from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174195/gdbus-error-when-trying-to-enable-second-screen) question but they do not help.

Answer (score 0):

I connected my laptop to my Samsung TV, fixed the problem. When I connected the laptop back on my DELL monitor, still no problem. So try that before complicating things in the terminal like i did at first.

Answer (score 0):

Disable graphics card drivers, restart, try if it works.

After booting on a live usb and managed to do exactly what I want with the displays, I concluded that something must be going on with the drivers of my graphics card. So I disabled them via System Settings>Additional Drivers, rebooted and everything worked as I wanted to.

Hope it helps you too.