# How to fix a second screen

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display-manager

This is not a generic question but rather a specific one for my system. I just freshly installed ubuntu 12.04 and did all the updates.

One of the updates told me to install additional hardware (for my nvidea geforce 610m graphics card), which gave me 2 options: the recommended one, or the post-release one. I picked recommended.

However the second screen wasnt working properly (monitor gets a signal, but nothing appears on it) and i get the error:

```
Failed to apply configuration: %s GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2' on object at path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/XRANDR
```

After googling this error i found various tips which whould solve the issue and i dont really know what i've done so far :( (i did mess around with arandr and xrandr)

problem is: tabs is my firefox now appear horribly oldschool looking and basicly I want to get that back and get my second screen to work.

Can anyone help? My laptop is an Asus A55VD.

Comment: Have you tried the post-release version of the driver? That should work and fix the issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDBus.Error when trying to enable second screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174195/gdbus-error-when-trying-to-enable-second-screen)

Answer (score 0):

It's  required to **disable Nvidia Optimus feature** in **BIOS**. In my case it fixed the problem. I see that your ASUS laptop also has got the feature. So it should help you

Answer (score 0):

solution to this problem is to simply use ubuntu 2D instead of 3D. 
1- on the log in screen there there is the ubuntu sign above the password field.
2- press on the Ubuntu Icon and then choose 2D instead of 3D, solve the problem like magic.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.