# Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied - Attempting to use second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I have 2 monitors connected to an AMD R9 380 GPU, one with DisplayPort (Primary) and one with HDMI (Secondary).

I first tried to use the secondary a few days ago without any problems, however when I tried to activate it a second time today the primary flashes off and back on (as normally happens when a second display is added) and the Keep/Revert dialog is shown, however the secondary remains off.

Looking through the syslog, I believe this error is the culprit as it occurs on each occasion I try to activate the secondary:

```
Config not applicable: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: The requested configuration is based on stale information
```

I found this related [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174195/gdbus-error-when-trying-to-enable-second-screen) and tried the suggestions noted in the top 2 answers with no success.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with all updates installed and no additional drivers or kernel modules.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10, really ?

Comment: Ha, Thats a good point. I blame lack of coffee. Should be 18.04, obviously.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1722708